# Real-time file synchronization

Tags: linux, files, synchronization

Is there any tool available to sync files between two or more linux servers immediately after writing the file in the disk? The `rsync` command does not suit me on this, because if I set `rsync` in cron, the minimum time I can set is 1 minute, but I need it on real-time basis.

Comment: Do you need synchronization from one read-write server to one or more read-only server(s), or do you need two-way synchronization (with propagation in both direction), or n-way? If you want two/n-way, how do you resolve conflicts?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Haven't used it myself but read about it recently. There is a daemon called `lsyncd`, which I presume does exactly what you need.

Read more about it [HERE](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Live-Sync-with-lsyncd)

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer.  `lsyncd` uses `inotify` & should be the fastest at the fs level. More at https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd. From that page: Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify or fsevents). It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes. By default this is rsync. Lsyncd is thus a light-weight live mirror solution that is comparatively easy to install not requiring new filesystems or block devices and does not hamper local filesystem performance.

Comment: I logged in, just to +1. Thanks for clarifying. This helped me make my decision for sync on two singleboards using SSDs.

Answer (score 23):

## Realtime File synchronisation between multiple servers in multi master mode

There is a good tool called `lsyncd` to sync files between multiple servers on real time basis. 
Here I have tried with two servers.

Hosts: Server1 and Server2

OS Used: CentOS 7

Install below packages on both the servers.

```
# yum install -y epel-release
# yum -y install lua lua-devel pkgconfig gcc asciidoc lsyncd
```

generate ssh-key in both the servers and add to `authorized_keys` file. *[add public key of server1 to server2's `authorized_keys` and public key of server2 to server1's `authorized_keys` file]*

### Server1 configuration

Open `/etc/lsyncd.conf` and comment out the default configuration using `--` at the beginning of the line and add below configuration to the file.

```
settings {
  logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
  delay = 1
}
sync {
  default.rsync,
  source="/home/test/public_html/",
  target="server2:/home/test/public_html/",
  rsync = {
    compress = true,
    acls = true,
    verbose = true,
    owner = true,
    group = true,
    perms = true,
    rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
  }
}
```

Change the target IP in `target` parameter.

You can change the `delay` parameter as per your requirement. Here it is set 1 second.

Now create the log directory.

```
# mkdir -p /var/log/lsyncd
```

Enable the `lsyncd` service to start automatically.

```
# systemctl enable lsyncd.service
```

Start the service.

```
# systemctl start lsyncd.service
```

### Server2 Configuration

Follow the same configuration as Server1 and change the `target` IP.

Now the synchronisation is set.

You can check the activity from `tailf /var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log`

Thanks to MelBurslan for his suggestion.

Comment: The delay parameter under settings function is not valid. Use **maxDelays** variable instead. I have implemented this tool. Its really powerful.

Comment: On Ubuntu (and probably on recents Debian releases), the config file must be placed in `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua`. See [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-synchronize-directories-using-lsyncd-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: As @HasanuzzamanSattar mentioned, the *delay* parameter should not be in the **settings** section of the configuration file. It should be in the **sync** section instead.

Answer (score 8):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) might be an option. It's extremely fast, transfer is encrypted and there are clients for multiple platforms. It uses "inotify" to sync changed files instantly.

Answer (score 6):

### [Inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)

Provide an interface to `inotify`, consisting of:

#### `inotifywait`

This command simply blocks for inotify events, making it appropriate for use in shell scripts. It can watch any set of files and directories, and can recursively watch entire directory trees.

#### `inotifywatch`

This command collects filesystem usage statistics and outputs counts of each inotify event.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to approach this with a clustered filesystem type solution - a simple sync between the two machines won't give you real-time response.

Comment: Actually those servers are at AWS. So we cannot get a cluster environment! Isn't there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

"SIOS Protection Suite for Linux" can offer this, on AWS.

http://www.linuxclustering.net/2016/03/21/step-by-step-how-to-configure-a-linux-failover-cluster-in-amazon-ec2-without-shared-storage-amazon-aws-sanless-cluster/#InstallConfigureCluster

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working config, for this example i used `/tmp/test` both as a local and a distant directory.

I had an error that said ssh-askpass wasn't installed:

```
sudo apt install ssh-askpass
```

I also needed to be using a non standard port for ssh.

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd-status.log",
    statusInterval = 1
}

sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    delete = false,
    source = "/tmp/test",
    rsync = {
    binary = "/usr/bin/rsync",
    archive = true,
    perms = true,
    owner = true,
    _extra = {"-a"},
    update = true,
    protect_args = true,
    sparse = true,
    rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -l src_username -i /home/src_username/.ssh/id_rsa",
    compress = true
},
ssh = {
    port = 6765,
    extra = {"-i","/home/src_username/.ssh/id_rsa"}
    },
host = "distant_username@hostname.xxx",
targetdir = "/tmp/test"
}
```

And after 4 hours of wandering:

```
Wed Feb  2 04:22:52 2022 Normal: --- Startup, daemonizing ---
Wed Feb  2 04:22:52 2022 Normal: recursive startup rsync: /tmp/test/ -> distant_username@hostname.xxx:/tmp/test/
Warning: Permanently added '[domain.xyz]:6765,[123.123.123.123]:6765' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Wed Feb  2 04:23:06 2022 Normal: Startup of "/tmp/test/" finished: 0
Wed Feb  2 04:24:13 2022 Normal: Calling rsync with filter-list of new/modified files/dirs 

sent 61 bytes  received 12 bytes  146.00 bytes/sec
total size is 57  speedup is 0.78
Wed Feb  2 04:24:13 2022 Normal: Finished a list after exitcode: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried lsyncd but had multiple issues, the daemon wouldnt sync files after a certain time, would only sync on a service restart.

I wrote a sync daemon called Poni - written in Crystal, very easy to configure Yaml config, listens on inotify and rsyncs, can specify additional options, see readme

https://github.com/perfecto25/poni