# Shared disk files synchronization

Tags: centos, mount, xfs

I have two Centos 7 servers with a shared disk mounted via fstab with:

```
/dev/sdb /mnt/shared   xfs  rw,suid,dev,noexec,auto,user,sync      0  0
```

I can see the disk and its content on both servers, but when I create a new file it is not automatically seen on the opposite server. If I umount and mount the disk, then the files will appear.

Executing `sync` after file creation also won't create the file.

I have installed lsyncd as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307046/real-time-file-synchronization) but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using clustered XFS? If not you will be at serious risk of corrupting your filesystem, if both are mounted r/w

Comment: @rustyshackleford Not clustered, thanks for the advice.!

Comment: No problem! Posted as an answer with some example clustered filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a shared block device you must ensure you are using a clustered filesystem if you intend for both servers to be able to write to the filesystem. Otherwise you will undoubtedly corrupt the file system.

Examples of clustered file systems:

```
GFS
Lustre
OCF
LizardFS
```

If it's an option, it may be simpler to mount an NFS share on both servers, as this will handle file locking etc.

Comment: btrfs would be a valid one? https://www.mopar4life.com/btrfs-centos-samba/

Comment: No `btrfs` is not a clustered filesystem, and it doesn't look like they plan on making it one: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Will_Btrfs_become_a_clustered_file_system